# Rails server raising "recycled object" error sometimes when instances object by object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, nested-forms

My problem it happens when adds part of form **dynamically** with `ajax` in the way `Rails` does. The asynchronous request is made when the event `input` of a `Node` object happens, and it's work. She sends it `stock_ingredient_f.object_id` defined in `data-action` attribute to controller and a helper method `form_parent` is defined to be accessed per the partial `_stock_ingredient_fields.haml`.

This is my form.

```
= form_for @stock_ingredient, remote: true do |stock_ingredient_f|
  .field
    = stock_ingredient_f.label "Enable/disable keyboard"
    = check_box :keyboard, :handler

  .field
    = stock_ingredient_f.label "Barcode"
    = text_field :ingredient, :barcode, value: stock_ingredient_f.object.ingredient.try(:barcode), class: "barcode", :'data-action' => ingredient_async_path(form_parent_object_id: stock_ingredient_f.object_id)

  - if @stock_ingredient.stock.present?
    .field
      = stock_ingredient_f.label "Stock"
      = stock_ingredient_f.number_field :stock
      %span.brown-color
        = "(#{@stock_ingredient.ingredient.net_weight_unit})"
```

This is a partial that should be load dynamically.

```
.ingredient-data

  .field
    %dl
      .line
        %dt
          Ingredient:
        %dd
          = "#{@ingredient.name}"

      .line
        %dt
          Stock:
        %dd.stock
          = "#{MeasurementUnits.humanize_for @ingredient.stock_ingredient.stock, resolve_unit_type(@ingredient.net_weight_unit)}"

  .field
    / the problem is raised here
    = form_parent.label "Stock"
    = form_parent.number_field :stock
    %span.brown-color
      = "(#{@ingredient.net_weight_unit})"

  .field
    = form_parent.submit "Save"
    = form_parent.button "Cancel", type: :reset
```

This is my `application_controller.rb`, where is defined the method `form_parent`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :js

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # when will has it login, change this line
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  def form_parent
    ObjectSpace._id2ref(params[:form_parent_object_id].to_i) if params[:form_parent_object_id]
  end
  helper_method :form_parent

  def root
    render "layouts/application", layout: false
  end

  protected

    def id
      params[:id]
    end

    def redirect_for_async_request location
      render js: "window.location='#{location}'"
    end

    def alert message
      render js: "window.alert('#{message}')"
    end

    # def no_cache
    #   if Rails.env.development?
    #     response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    #   end
    # end

end
```

When the page is refreshed and the request is fired again, the server says: `ActionView::Template::Error (0x002ac5927b9058 is recycled object)` probably does reference to response of `ObjectSpace._id2ref`.
I belive that the garbage collector is involved.

**UPDATE application_controller.rb**

```
def form_parent
  @@form_parent
end

def store_form object
  @@form_parent = object
end
helper_method :form_parent, :store_form
```

**form**

```
= form_for @stock_ingredient, remote: true do |stock_ingredient_f|
  - store_form stock_ingredient_f

  .field
    = stock_ingredient_f.label "Enable/disable keyboard"
    = check_box :keyboard, :handler

  .field
    = stock_ingredient_f.label "Barcode"
    = text_field :ingredient, :barcode, value: stock_ingredient_f.object.ingredient.try(:barcode), class: "barcode", :'data-action' => ingredient_async_path

  - if @stock_ingredient.stock.present?
    .field
      = stock_ingredient_f.label "Stock"
      = stock_ingredient_f.number_field :stock
      %span.brown-color
        = "(#{@stock_ingredient.ingredient.net_weight_unit})"
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means you are trying to access an object that has been garbage collected, as you may have suspected. This happened because the object id was from a previous time, and once the id was sent to the browser, no more references to that object existed, so ruby cleaned up that object.

Although it may not always be true, it's best to think of each request as running in a new, separate ruby process. If you want to 'pass' data between requests, you have to either send it to the client (if you don't mind the data being changed) or store it in a session, or store it in a database. You cannot pass around objects the way you do here.

Comment: I stored it in a class variable, because did'n make it in ```session```.

Answer (score 0):

You suspect correctly - the object with that object_id has been garbage collected. I'm not sure why you are doing this, but it sounds like a really bad idea. It's not completely clear to me what `form_parent` is (a FormBuilder instance ?) but at a guess you should be passing the id of an object in the database, fetching the object from the database and using that to get a fresh `FormBuilder` instance from `form_for` or `fields_for`.

Even if you can make your current approach work it would limit you to a single rails instance, whereas any serious deployment of an application uses multiple instances spread across 2 or more servers.

Comment: Yes, ```form_parent``` returns a ```FormBuilder``` instance. Thanks.